# How to find out specific API usage in Windows Store Apps (UWP)

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api, appinsights

I want to find out whether the installed UWP app from a 3rd party vendor uses a specific Windows API or not.

I have investigated various options such as Sysinternal tools or Graph APIs and searched web lot, however, I find anything useful for UWP app.